# woocommerce: extract the value referred to field meta_value

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to extract the value referred to s:7:" "

field meta_value = O:59:"Importer\application\libs\pextractor\parser\Product":26:{s:6:"domain";s:7:"ebay.com";}

what did I do wrong?

```
// Run the query
$query = "SELECT wp.id, wp.post_title, wpm.meta_key, wpm.meta_value
          FROM wp_posts wp
          INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wpm ON wpm.post_id = wp.id
          WHERE wp.id = 7949
          AND wpm.meta_key = '_product'";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);

// Check if there are any results
if (!empty($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $meta_value = unserialize($row->meta_value); // Deserialize the value
        if (isset($meta_value['domain']) && $meta_value['domain'] == 'ebay.com') {
            echo $meta_value['domain'];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No results found.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your core is almost correct, I changed the code little `(for loop)` but that includes error handling for potential issues during data `unserialization` and checks the data type of the `unserialized` value, ensuring it correctly accesses the 'domain' property from the serialized object stored in your WordPress database.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
        // Handle potential errors during unserialization
        $meta_value = @unserialize($row->meta_value);
        if ($meta_value === false && $row->meta_value !== 'b:0;') {
            echo "Error unserializing the value";
        } else {
            if (is_object($meta_value) && isset($meta_value->domain) && $meta_value->domain == 'ebay.com') {
                echo $meta_value->domain;
            } elseif (is_array($meta_value) && isset($meta_value['domain']) && $meta_value['domain'] == 'ebay.com') {
                echo $meta_value['domain'];
            }
        }
    }
```